# SQL Server index usage and implicit conversion

Tags: sql-server

Can someone please explain the following behavior to me, let me know if table definitions etc. would help.

I have a query executed on SQL Server 2016 SP2, all tables have the default clustered index on the primary key column, which is an `IDENTITY` column:

```
SELECT a.smallint_col
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON b.int_col = a.int_col
WHERE a.int_col = 123 AND b.varchar_col = 12345;
```

This query returns an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ABC123' to data type int.

`'ABC123'` is the value of a row in `TableB.varchar_col`.

I understand this query forces SQL Server to perform implicit conversion on `TableB.varchar_col` because it is passed without single quotes.

I can see from Include Live Query Statistics that this query is trying to use a non-clustered index scan on an index defined on TableB as:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [varchar_col] 
ON [TableB] ([varchar_col])
```

and an index seek on an index defined on TableA as:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [int_col] 
ON [TableA] ([int_col])
```

If I force the query to use the clustered indexes on each table by using `WITH (INDEX(1))`, the query returns successfully. I know that if I quote the value correctly `'12345'`, the query also returns successfully (for some unknown reason our code passes it without the quotes) and I think that is the real solution.

However, I'd like to understand the behavior of SQL Server here. Why is the clustered index scan able to perform the implicit conversion without throwing the error but the non clustered index scan can't?

Comment: To understand the plan, one must SEE the plan, the DDL of the objects involved, and the actual query. Don't post images - use [Ozar](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) to post your plan and link it in your question.

Comment: Try using `.... AND b.varchar_col = '12345';`. If you **don't have** the single quotes around this value, SQL Server will try to convert both sides of the equal sign to the datatype with higher precedence - which is `int` - it SQL Server tries (and fails) to convert `b.varchar_col` to `int` - hence the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely what's happening here is that the order at which SQL Server is applying the clauses.

When you get the failure, the data engine is likely applying the clause `b.varchar_col = 12345` first. As a result, when a value that isn't able to be (implicitly) converted to an `int` is compared the query fails.

For the times it works, then likely the clause `a.int_col = 123` is being evaluated first. When this is applied, any rows that remain contain values in `b.varchar_col` that *can* be implicitly converted, and thus no failure.

Like you said, however, the real solution here is to correct your application layer. Likely you should be using a parametrised query, rather than (injecting?) raw values. Then you control the datatypes:

```
SELECT a.smallint_col
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON b.int_col = a.int_col
WHERE a.int_col = @IntParam and b.varchar_col = @VarcharParam;
```

In your application code, you can then define `@IntParam` as an `int` and `@VarcharParam` as a `varchar`, meaning that no implicit conversion can happen *apart* from perhaps if your application passes `12345` to parameter `@VarcharParam`.

How you parametrise your application is a different question though (seeing as we don't even know what language your application uses, we can't even provide an example, I'm afraid).

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. The application is Classic ASP using VBScript, the majority of queries are passed as raw T-SQL. 
I'm working with our developers looking to parameterise correctly and resolve a deluge of data type mismatches which are causing a lot of implicit conversions.